# I am trying to search a word document for instances where an italicized word is touching a non italicized word

Tags: microsoft-word, search, wildcards

I have many large word documents with mixed text in them.  I am trying to find a way to find when I have an italicized word connected to a nonitalicized word.

i.e. *This form*starts

I know how to search for individual characters using wildcards such as ([A-z])([A-z]) but I cannot figure out how to tell it that I want to look for the case of the first variable being italics.

Thank you beforehand,

Brad

Comment: Would you be open to a solution in LibreOffice?

Comment: I believe if you are to do this in Word, that you'll need to set up a macro. Are you willing and able to use a macro? If so, once a partial italicized word is found what do you need to do with it?

Comment: I don't mind using a macro, but the reason I need to find this is that italicized words are smashed into non italicized words so I would need to insert a space between them.

Answer (score 0):

If the italicised word is at beginning of mashed up word, you could try a series of wildcard find and replaces (assuming no highlighting used in existing document already).  The following worked for me - highlight anything italic, highlight any non-italic whole words, highlight any spaces/punctuation marks, so all that should now be left unhighlighted is the non-italics part of joined words.  Final replace is to add space at start of "end of words" ie the non-italics part.  Then you would just select your entire document and remove all highlighting.  (I'd always use a copy of the document to test though before making major change, and run a comparison afterwards to check that all that has changed is what I expect to see.)
[image]